# HTML CSS: Fixed Menu with submenu, Submenu is appearing before hovering over menu

Tags: html, css

I have a menu, which when I hover on menu item, a sub menu appears. The problem is if I take my mouse towards the area where sub menu would *usually* appear (the area covered on screen by sub menu when I hover on menu), the sub menu is visible. In other words, it appears even when I am not hovering on menu item. I guess it may be due to some z-indexing issue?

Please let me know if more expanation is needed.

```css
.menu-wrap {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 4;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  background: #10345A;
}
.menu {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  text-align: left;
}
.menu li {
  margin: 0px;
  list-style: none;
}
.menu a {
  transition: all linear 0.15s;
  color: white;
}
.menu li:hover > a,
.menu .current-item > a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  background-color: #FF6600;
}
.menu .arrow {
  font-size: 11px;
  line-height: 0%;
}
/*----- Top Level -----*/

.menu > ul > li {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 19px;
}
.menu > ul > li > a {
  padding: 10px 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  text-decoration: none;
}
.menu > ul > li:hover > a,
.menu > ul > .current-item > a {
  background: #10345A;
  color: #FF6600;
}
/*----- Bottom Level -----*/

.menu li:hover .sub-menu {
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 1;
}
.sub-menu {
  width: 300px;
  padding: 5px 0px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity linear 0.15s;
  background: gray;
}
.sub-menu li {
  display: block;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.sub-menu li a {
  padding: 10px 30px;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.sub-menu li a:hover,
.sub-menu .current-item a {
  background: #10345A;
  color: #FF6600;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu-wrap">
  <nav class="menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Menu 2  <span class="arrow">&#9660;</span></a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li><a href="#"><span class="arrow">&#9658;</span>  Submenu 1</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#"><span class="arrow">&#9658;</span>  Submenu 2</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu 3  <span class="arrow">&#9660;</span></a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li><a href="#"><span class="arrow">&#9658;</span>  Submenu 3</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#"><span class="arrow">&#9658;</span>  Submenu 4</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#"><span class="arrow">&#9658;</span>  Submenu 5</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

As an aside, I'm also not able to center align the menu, it's always left aligned.

Comment: Please try to only paste the relevant code and try to use something like a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) to show how your code is behaving.

Comment: Your problem is, that your submenu is still there and only the opacity is set to 0. Use display:none and display:block instead!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this is happening, is because you are hiding `.sub-menu` with `opacity:0`, so basically it is still there and the `:hover` on the parent `ul` is being activated because the child `ul` is being hovered over.

You need to have it set to `display:none` and then `display:block` it upon hovering.

The problem with this though, you lose your animation effect, so I suggest using keyframes as I've indicated below.

```css
.menu-wrap {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 4;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  background: #10345A;
}
.menu {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  text-align: left;
}
.menu li {
  margin: 0px;
  list-style: none;
}
.menu a {
  transition: all linear 0.15s;
  color: white;
}
.menu li:hover > a,
.menu .current-item > a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  background-color: #FF6600;
}
.menu .arrow {
  font-size: 11px;
  line-height: 0%;
}
/*----- Top Level -----*/

.menu > ul > li {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 19px;
}
.menu > ul > li > a {
  padding: 10px 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  text-decoration: none;
}
.menu > ul > li:hover > a,
.menu > ul > .current-item > a {
  background: #10345A;
  color: #FF6600;
}
/*----- Bottom Level -----*/

/* ADD THESE */
@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
    from { opacity: 0; }
      to { opacity: 1; }
}
@keyframes fadeIn {
    from { opacity: 0; }
      to { opacity: 1; }
}
.menu li:hover .sub-menu {
  z-index: 1;
  display: block; /* ADD ME */
  -webkit-animation: fadeIn 0.15s; /* ADD ME */
  animation: fadeIn 0.15s; /* ADD ME */
}
.sub-menu {
  width: 300px;
  padding: 5px 0px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: 0;
  background: gray;
  display: none; /* ADD ME */
}
.sub-menu li {
  display: block;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.sub-menu li a {
  padding: 10px 30px;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.sub-menu li a:hover,
.sub-menu .current-item a {
  background: #10345A;
  color: #FF6600;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu-wrap">
  <nav class="menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Menu 2  <span class="arrow">&#9660;</span></a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li><a href="#"><span class="arrow">&#9658;</span>  Submenu 1</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#"><span class="arrow">&#9658;</span>  Submenu 2</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu 3  <span class="arrow">&#9660;</span></a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li><a href="#"><span class="arrow">&#9658;</span>  Submenu 3</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#"><span class="arrow">&#9658;</span>  Submenu 4</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#"><span class="arrow">&#9658;</span>  Submenu 5</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks mate. It worked. Can't upvote due to lack of rep points.

Answer (score 1):

In `.submenu` you have `opacity: 0` so the element is there but is transparent. That's why it's showing when you hover over it (as you set opacity back to 1 on hover).

Have a look at my fiddle where I changed it to make use of `display: none` instead: https://jsfiddle.net/mcowx5j6/1/ (also centered the `.menu`)

Answer (score 0):

```
.menu {
width:100%;
margin:0px;
text-align:left;
```

change  this as

```
.menu {
width:100%;
margin:0px;
text-align:center;
```

Comment: That will align the sub menu as well. I want that to be right aligned

Comment: ok u want only menu to align in right , and sub menus should align center ri8??

Comment: dude its working properly un my system, may i know which platform u r using??

Comment: I'll try it once again and see. I guess I tried your option as well, but can't remember much as my main focus was on sub-menu. I'm use IE9. It has to run on that. Anyways,. thanks for the help mate